# Own request except field in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

If i've a requet class and rules function in it:

```
class BookRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'isbn13' => 'required|digits:13|unique:App\Models\Product,isbn13,except,' . $this->isbn13
            //or '..|unique:books,isbn13,except,'.$this->id
        ];
    }
}
```

How do update that it doesn't read the current row? This Request i want to use for updating and inserting.

Comment: You mean that the unique constraint shouldn't be applied when updating the model?

Comment: yes, it shouldn't be aplied.. And also $this->id has no value. Also "unique:books,isbn13,{$this->isbn13},isbn13" not work. And "unique:books,isbn13,{$this->id},id", cannot use because $this->id is "null".

Comment: Could you try using `Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this-> isbn13)`?  like the docs describe? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: could you add an example request to your question? Is the book id part of the request?

Comment: I found a solution. I inserted into form <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$book->id ?: 0}}" />, and then "..|unique:products,isbn13,{$this->id}|.." works.

Comment: ah great! otherwise you could also extract it from the url